# How do I add an image to a tweet or how does twitter decide which image urls to render

Tags: image, twitter

If I post a tweet with a link to a picture it will only display the link. But if twitpic post an image link (or rather a link to a page with an image) twitter will render the image (smaller albeit).

I know twitter now has [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) but those appear to be for reading and not writing.

And yeah I could use twitpic but I rather not since we already have the images saved and ready to go.

Basically how do you become like: twitpic, lockerz, photobucket, yfrog... so on so that twitter recognizes your links as images.

*Update: I know twitter will provide upload image api soon but I would rather have the image content on my site.*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:** As noted in comments, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760685/244353) for updated information. Twitter now supports a more straightforward way for achieving the same effect.

Twitter Cards overview: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/abouts-cards

---

Twitter scrapes the URL for images and display them inline for the companies it has *partenered* with.

The current list includes: DailyBooth, DeviantART, Etsy, Flickr, Justin.TV, Kickstarter, Kiva, Photozou, Plixi, Twitgoo, TwitPic, TwitVid, USTREAM, Vimeo, yfrog, and YouTube.
[twitter.com/newtwitter](http://twitter.com/newtwitter)

They also support iTunes, blip.tv, Instagram, Rdio, SlideShare, and Dipdive: http://blog.twitter.com/2010/12/now-playing-on-newtwitter-embedded.html

So for you to become like twitpic etc, you need to have a partnership with them. There is no API trick for that. The other way is to use one of those services which is not waht you prefer but seems to be the easiest way out.

Comment: Of course this begs the question how do I become a partner but I guess that is dependent on the provider. Kind of seems unfair to new startups but I guess thats capitalism.

Comment: @Adam Gent: Agree with you. Although with media(images/video etc) there are usually privacy, license, copyright implications, not to mention security implications. It is better to trust on handful of partners to provide a better QoS.

Comment: This answer is tremendously outdated as all sites can now render cards. See @missmatsuko's answer.

Answer (score 8):

The top answer to this question is out of date.

Twitter will now show an image for a link shared in a tweet if it contains the following meta info:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{full/absolute image url here}">
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am trying this but the image has a href to the page from where its shared, can i not just tweet a image but not have a  href to the image. basically get the same effect as uploading the image?

Answer (score 6):

Twitter now has an API for what they call Cards. It is using HTML Meta tags just like the Facebook implementation.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

It is only for white listed approved domain now.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter decides.... basically they are looking in entities / or using a regex to pick the image url out. I am not so sure about twitpic images being rendered on the twitter.com domain.... I thought they only render images through their media service.

If you are trying to avoid legal issues (in terms of who owns image) best to avoid twitpic.

Comment: I think twitter just adds companies that do pictures uploads and lots of them to "enhance" the user experience. BTW you can clearly see that its a picture upload on twitter.com (in the right hand corner it will have a media icon).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too so I made an app for it (possibly overkill?). Use `http://jpg.party/SOME_IMAGE_URL` and Twitter will do the right thing and put it in a card.

Comment: Is the jpg.party a Twitter thing it recognises, or just a random URL

Answer (score 0):

You can add Images to a tweet when You specify the "media_Ids" in the Api call (statuses/update).
To upload media files You have to read this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media

I´m working on an automatic solution for this. It´s a bit tricky, but You can find a solutionn at time.