# Custom Twitter Pictures in stream

Tags: api, twitter

There are multiple servies that let you insert pictures and videos into the twitter stream. - with instagram and youtube being two of the first that come to mind.

The question is - how do I do that?

If I want a custom image, and I want to link them back to my site - do I have to use the /statuses/update_with_media.json endpoint (which adds it to pics.twitter.com) along with my own link? Meaning two links?

Is there a trick to how these sites do it, or are they officially supported by Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play "in-line" on Twitter.com. Only a select few services will allow this.

in case of videos for example, refer to this article on Twitters website.

https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/109-tweets-messages/articles/75603-how-to-post-videos-on-twitter

You would need two links if you wanted to host a picture on Twitter itself and have it link to another place. The pictures hyper-link would be converted and another link would need to be added next to it.

more:

[How do I add an image to a tweet or how does twitter decide which image urls to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931396/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-tweet-or-how-does-twitter-decide-which-image-urls-to/)

[Is there a public API or meta data to integrate with Twitter new media system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172666/is-there-a-public-api-or-meta-data-to-integrate-with-twitter-new-media-system/)

(PS great CI articles, thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Looks like the answer is: You don't unless you're butt-buddies with Twitter?