# Is there a way to make a Facebook/Twitter share button that shares a div's innerHTML?

Tags: sharing

Here is a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/bNEGXv) that helps explain what I'm doing.

I have a site that generates a random fact with Javascript, and puts it into a `div` with the `id="fact"`. Below this `div` is a simple "Share on Twitter" link using a very basic sharing link I found online:

`http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thewikifix.com&text=Simple Share Buttons&hashtags=thewikifix`

This works great and it's very simple, but I'm wondering if there's a way to share the contents of the

`<div id="fact"></div>`.

Basically, instead of

`"text=SimpleShareButtons"`

it would be

`"text={document.getElementId("fact").innerHTML}"`

(Obviously the second part is fictional, I know I can't just put a Javascript string into a link in HTML).

Is there a way to do what I'm doing? Even a completely different way of doing this is welcome as well.

Comment: You should be able to do this using js. I'll try to help. One caveat, your "fact" text is too long in the example (96)... do you want to trim it?

Comment: @wahwahwah Thanks! And that's a good question. I think I will leave it as is, even if the fact is too long. So the sharer will decide what to trim to fit the text in the tweet, when the tweet sharing window is brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two changes that were made to the HTML for simplicity's sake. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2yzs24j/2/) the code that should do what you're looking for:

[css not changed]

**HTML:**

```
<p id="fact">Babe Ruth once pitched a 4-pitch walk to start a game, got angry at the umpire's calls, and punched him, getting ejected. Reliever Ernie Shore came in and retired every batter for a combined no-hitter.</p>
<p id="sharing"><a id="factLink" href="#" target="_blank">share on twitter</a>
</p>
```

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
 $('#factLink').click(function () {

    // Get the fact text
    var factText = $('#fact').text();

    // Convert to string
    var factStr = factText.toString();

    // Fact length
    var factLen = factText.length;

    // This section formats the text that is too long, remove it if needed
    if (factLen > 103) { // max chacters allowed
        // trim, and allow space for '...'"
        var trimFact = factStr.substring(0, 100);
        var trimFact = trimFact.trim(); //<-- ensures the last character isnt ' '
        factStr = trimFact + "...";
    }

    // Update the link
    var linkRef = "http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thewikifix.com&text=" + factStr + "&hashtags=thewikifix";

    $('#factLink').attr('href', linkRef);

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to share am image along with the text (shown in ur fiddle)??

Comment: @VP - that's a [bit more complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931396/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-tweet-or-how-does-twitter-decide-which-image-urls-to-r) but if I understand the link correctly, if it's a partner site to Twitter, adding the url *should* make the image render in the post

Comment: I found here that their is no need of `clientId` or `AppId` like gmail or faebook. My question is their is any issues can cause regarding without using it?

Answer (score 0):

Your psudo code is pretty much exactly what you want to do. You just need to pass it as a variable

```
var inner = document.getElementId("fact").innerHTML;
"text=" + inner
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe something like this? (referring to my CodePen):

`document.getElementById(#sharing).innerHTML = "<a href='http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thewikifix.com&text=" + document.getElementById(#fact).innerHTML + "&hashtags=thewikifix' target='_blank'>share on twitter</a>";`

Comment: Yep, that looks totally fine. I like to separate selectors into vars but yeah, thats all you need to do!